# KeyError: '' in python/tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keyerror

I am trying to make a text generator code, but the following line keeps giving me an error:

```
X[0, (sequence_length - len(seed)) + t, char2int[char]] = 1
```

The error that this line gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m8\Desktop\programing_stuff\python stuff\text generator\app.py", line 65, in <module>
    X[0, (sequence_length - len(seed)) + t, char2int[char]] = 1
KeyError: '3'
```

It was working so far, and i didn't change the code so i don't know whats the issue.
I think the keyError is coming from the randomly generated seed but i don't know how to fix the problem

full code(note: this is only the code for the generation, the other script for creating the .pickle file is separate, but i don't use any other variables from it):

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import tqdm
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Activation
import os
import string
import random
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import textwrap



sequence_length = 100
# dataset file path
FILE_PATH = "data/shrek.txt"
# FILE_PATH = "data/python_code.py"
BASENAME = os.path.basename(FILE_PATH)


S = random.randint(5, 20)
ran = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = S))

seed = str(ran).lower()

# load vocab dictionaries
char2int = pickle.load(open(f"{BASENAME}-char2int.pickle", "rb"))
int2char = pickle.load(open(f"{BASENAME}-int2char.pickle", "rb"))
vocab_size = len(char2int)


# building the model
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(256, input_shape=(sequence_length, vocab_size), return_sequences=True),
    Dropout(0.3),
    LSTM(256),
    Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax"),
])


# load the optimal weights
model.load_weights(f"results/{BASENAME}-{sequence_length}.h5")


s = seed
n_chars = 120
generated = ""
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(n_chars), "Generating text"):
    # make the input sequence
    X = np.zeros((1, sequence_length, vocab_size))
    for t, char in enumerate(seed):
        X[0, (sequence_length - len(seed)) + t, char2int[char]] = 1
    # predict the next character
    predicted = model.predict(X, verbose=0)[0]
    # converting the vector to an integer
    next_index = np.argmax(predicted)
    # converting the integer to a character
    next_char = int2char[next_index]
    # add the character to results
    generated += next_char
    # shift seed and the predicted character
    seed = seed[1:] + next_char

print("Seed:", s)
print("Generated text:")


if generated[0] == " ":
    new_string = generated[1:]
    generated = new_string

if generated[-2] == " ":
    new_string = generated[:-1]
    generated = new_string

generated = ''.join(('"',generated,'"'))

print(generated)
```

Comment: Sems as if `char2int[char]` throws he error. The dictionary `char2int` doesn't have an entry with the key `"3"`.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias , `char2int` does seem to be the issue but i still don't know the reason. It sometimes doesn't throw an error and it works on older .pickle files. I will update if i find the reason.